# JSDoc error? module exports appears as global

Tags: javascript, node.js, documentation, jsdoc

JSDoc error?: module exports appears as global

Hi,
I am trying to document a small project I have which is made with modularity in mind. For this reason I have the following code structure:

/├── app
│   └── modules
│       └── Application
│           ├── app
│           │   └── Application.Common.js
│           └── cln
│               └── Application.GlobalDocumentation.js
│       └── ModuleA
│       └── ModuleB
/….
└── package.json

I have one module called Application which will be the glue among the rest of the modules, and one of its duties is define the public interfaces that the rest of the modules (ModuleA, ModuleB, etc)  need to implement.
I have created the file Application.GlobalDocumentation.js just for documentation purposes,  to document this global interfaces (which for the moment is just a function).

```
/**
* Client-side Constructor Function that generates client side index interfaces
* @name ClientModuleConstructor
* @function
* @global
* @param {string} something
* @return {object}
*/
```

And Application.Common.js is a file where shared logic will be placed:

```
/**
* This module handle the initialization, construction and the lifecycle of the application
* @module ApplicationCommon
*/
var requiredModule = require('fs')

/**
* WHY THIS DOCUMENTATION APPEARS AS GLOBAL?!
* @param {Array<ClientModuleConstructor>} applicationModuleConstructors Parameter details
* @return {string}
*/
export default function (applicationModuleConstructors)
{
    return {
        something: applicationModuleConstructors
    };
};
```

Questions:

1. I don't know why the exports documentation of the Application.Common.js file appears as global, which is just of that file/module.
2. How should I document that the exports of a module is a function with the signature ClientModuleConstructor?
3. Is something wrong with the previous snippets?

Notes:

- I am using jsdoc 3.4.1

Thanks in advance.